Proof of $\frac{\Phi_n'(x)}{\Phi_n(x)} = \frac{1}{x^n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_k(n)x^{k-1}$
Let $c_k(n)$ denote Ramanujan's sum, and $\Phi_n(x)$ be the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial. Prove that
$$\frac{\Phi_n'(x)}{\Phi_n(x)} = \frac{1}{x^n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_k(n)x^{k-1}$$

My attempt was to start with the fact that
$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{d\mid n}(1-x^d)^{\mu(n/d)}$$
taking logs
$$\ln \Phi_n(x) = \sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)\ln (1-x^d)$$
and hence differentiating we get to the following formula
$$\frac{\Phi_n'(x)}{\Phi_n(x)} = \sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)\frac{-dx^{d-1}}{1-x^d}$$
Here is where I'm not sure how to continue. I know an identity for Ramanujan's sum which is $$c_k(n) \sum_{d\mid (n, k)}\mu (k/d) d$$
This seems like the appropriate way to continue, however I don't understand the way in which this can be used to end up with a sum from $k=1$ to $n$ like desired. If anyone can demonstrate it that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

First we use the definition of Cyclotomic polynomials
$$
\log(\Phi_n(x)) = \sum_{\substack{1\leq p\leq n \\ \gcd(p, n) = 1}}\log (x - e^{2i\pi p/n}),
$$
We differentiate and use geometric sums (backwards)
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\Phi'_n(x)}{\Phi_n(x)}
&= \sum_{\substack{1\leq p\leq n \\ \gcd(p, n) = 1}} \frac{1}{x - e^{2i\pi p/n}} \\
&= x^{-1}\sum_{\substack{1\leq p\leq n \\ \gcd(p, n) = 1}} xe^{-2i\pi p/n} \frac{1}{x e^{-2i\pi p/n} - 1} \\
&= \frac{x^{-1}}{x^n-1} \sum_{\substack{1\leq p\leq n \\ \gcd(p, n) = 1}} xe^{-2i\pi p/n} \frac{(x e^{-2i\pi p/n})^n-1}{x e^{-2i\pi p/n} - 1} \\
&= \frac{x^{-1}}{x^n-1} \sum_{\substack{1\leq p\leq n \\ \gcd(p, n) = 1}} \sum_{k=1}^n (x e^{-2i\pi p/n})^k \\
&= \frac{1}{x^n-1} \sum_{k=1}^n x^{k-1} \sum_{\substack{1\leq p\leq n \\ \gcd(p, n) = 1}} e^{-2i\pi k p/n} \\
&= \frac{1}{x^n-1} \sum_{k=1}^n x^{k-1} c_n(-k).
\end{align}
$$
And since Ramanujan's sum are symmetric, this conslude the proof. But you either miswritten your formula or you're using a convention different from Wikipedia's.

Look at page 11 of this. They also seem to use such convention. Are they somehow the same?

If you compare his eq. (2.5) to the "von Sterneck" section of wikipedia, you see that his $r_k(n)$ is Wikipedia's $c_n(k)$.

Ah okay, I didn't see that. Thank you for this detail!
